# allow ssh outgoing with iptables default policy as drop

Tags: ssh, iptables, vps

Good day all

My VPS allows incoming ssh connections as required (see rule),

however attempting outgoing ssh connections fails to connect with

```
$ ssh xyz.ddns.net
ssh: connect to host xyz.ddns.net port 22: Connection timed out
```

I have found setting the default policy to accept allows outgoing ssh connections

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)

ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* SSH-SECURE IN (iface:ALL) */ state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

> NEW - The connection has not yet been seen.
>
> RELATED - The connection is new, but is related to another connection already > permitted.

should allow these outgoing connections?

Comment: It should. That doesn't mean there aren't other firewalls preventing it..

Comment: @NickW there are no other firewalls preventing it...

Comment: assuming ddns.net means a dyndns service: Port forwarding on a NAT network perhaps?
IS this problem on all outgoing ssh connections or only on a specific one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This rule allows INCOMING packets which have destination port 22.

When you establish outgoing connection to remote port 22, your local port is selected randomly.
You should have rule

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

otherwise remote server's answers can not reach your server.

Comment: ahh thanks, this solves my problem, I knew this rule was hiding somewhere xD